# How to force download zip file in php (zend framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zip

I'm triying to download a zip file using the following code

```
$archive_file_name ='facturas.zip';
header("Content-Type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$archive_file_name);
header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile($archive_file_name);
```

But this return the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4q8h.png), and the download don't start.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to download the file you need to set content type to octet-stream, not the actual content type.

```
header("Content-type: application/x-octet-stream");
```

Also, you should add `exit;` after the readfile (credits to [Daniel Gadawski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320081/daniel-gadawski))